# Prevent playing games on Google homepage with Screen Time

Tags: google-search

We use Apple Screen Time for parental controls.

Our kids have access to google.com for searches.  Access to other websites has to be granted by us (parents).

If they search for "play tic tac toe" on the google.com home page they can play these games directly from google.com.  We don't allow access to game sites but they bypass these controls using this approach.

How can you restrict playing games directly from google.com with Screen Time while allowing access to Google search?

Comment: There comes a point where you start chasing your own tail, trying to close down all the loop-holes. The older they get, the more they will discover. I would suggest talking to them, and asking them not to exploit the loophole, otherwise, access will be revoked. Also, https://parenting.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Google doesn't provide any way to do this.

Blocking JavaScript from google.com would probably stop such games from working, although that does change the appearance of the search results page.

Comment: Interesting suggestion.  Is there a way to block JavaScript using Screen Time?

Comment: I don't know if Screen time allow to block javascript but you can do this from you browser settings. For example in chrome you can find under `Site Settings`